# Shift dataset dimension (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to shift the dimension of a dataset below:

**Data**

```
location    range   status  type    Q1 28   Q2 28
NY          Low     Re      AA      2       0
NY          Low     Gr      AA      2       2
NY          Low     Re      BB      0       0
NY          Low     Gr      BB      0       0
NY          Low     Re      DD      0       2
NY          Low     Gr      DD      2       2
NY          Low     Re      SS      0       0
NY          Low     Gr      SS      0       0
CA          Med     Re      AA      0       4
CA          Med     Gr      AA      2       0
CA          Med     Re      BB      0       2
CA          Med     Gr      BB      0       0
CA          Med     Re      DD      0       6
CA          Med     Gr      DD      2       0
CA          Med     Re      SS      0       2
CA          Med     Gr      SS      0       0
```

**Desired**

```
location    range status type   quarter count
NY          Low   Re     AA     Q1 28   2
NY          Low   Gr     AA     Q1 28   2
NY          Low   Re     BB     Q1 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     BB     Q1 28   0
NY          Low   Re     DD     Q1 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     DD     Q1 28   2
NY          Low   Re     SS     Q1 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     SS     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Re     AA     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Gr     AA     Q1 28   2
CA          Med   Re     BB     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Gr     BB     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Re     DD     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Gr     DD     Q1 28   2
CA          Med   Re     SS     Q1 28   0
CA          Med   Gr     SS     Q1 28   0
NY          Low   Re     AA     Q2 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     AA     Q2 28   2
NY          Low   Re     BB     Q2 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     BB     Q2 28   0
NY          Low   Re     DD     Q2 28   2
NY          Low   Gr     DD     Q2 28   2
NY          Low   Re     SS     Q2 28   0
NY          Low   Gr     SS     Q2 28   0
CA          Med   Re     AA     Q2 28   4
CA          Med   Gr     AA     Q2 28   0
CA          Med   Re     BB     Q2 28   2
CA          Med   Gr     BB     Q2 28   0
CA          Med   Re     DD     Q2 28   6
CA          Med   Gr     DD     Q2 28   0
CA          Med   Re     SS     Q2 28   2
CA          Med   Gr     SS     Q2 28   0
```

**Doing**

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['location', 'range'], var_name='quarter', value_name='count')
```

however not all of the data is pivoting. Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify all columns in `id_vars` parameter which need not melting:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['location', 'range','status','type'], 
                 var_name='quarter', 
                 value_name='count')
```

Or dynamic get all columns not starting by `Q`:

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if not c.startswith('Q')]  
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=cols, var_name='quarter', value_name='count')
```

Or get all columns if not pattern `Q` + number + space + number(s):

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains(r'^Q\d\s+\d+$')].tolist()
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=cols, var_name='quarter', value_name='count')
```

```
print (df)

   location range status type quarter  count
0        NY   Low     Re   AA   Q1 28      2
1        NY   Low     Gr   AA   Q1 28      2
2        NY   Low     Re   BB   Q1 28      0
3        NY   Low     Gr   BB   Q1 28      0
4        NY   Low     Re   DD   Q1 28      0
5        NY   Low     Gr   DD   Q1 28      2
6        NY   Low     Re   SS   Q1 28      0
7        NY   Low     Gr   SS   Q1 28      0
8        CA   Med     Re   AA   Q1 28      0
9        CA   Med     Gr   AA   Q1 28      2
10       CA   Med     Re   BB   Q1 28      0
11       CA   Med     Gr   BB   Q1 28      0
12       CA   Med     Re   DD   Q1 28      0
...
27       CA   Med     Gr   BB   Q2 28      0
28       CA   Med     Re   DD   Q2 28      6
29       CA   Med     Gr   DD   Q2 28      0
30       CA   Med     Re   SS   Q2 28      2
31       CA   Med     Gr   SS   Q2 28      0
```